# In flutter check the type of user in firebase to direct him to a specific page

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I need to know what is the type of logged in users which is stored in firestore to direct them to a specific page.

Comment: I believe if you refer to ```User``` object of a specific user, you would get some properties of the user but if you want extra properties, you may want to create a document to deal with the properties of users
Refer to this documentation https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase/User-class.html

Comment: If you've stored the type of user in the database, you'll need to load it from there when the user signs in and then redirect to the correct screen. Did you try anything yet?